# JS randomize lineTo

Tags: javascript, random, draw

I need to randomize the coordinates of shapes.
I know I need to somehow introduce the Math.floor(Math.Random * num); line in there, but nothing I do seems to work.

This is the block with the filled in coordinates I am trying to randomize.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth="5";
ctx.strokeStyle="black";  
ctx.moveTo;
ctx.lineTo(100,20);
ctx.lineTo(30,400);
ctx.lineTo(300,40);
ctx.lineTo(10,20);
ctx.stroke();
```

I've searched and searched and found nothing directly on this for some reason.
Sorry this is such a basic question too, I'm really new to this and still learning the basics.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? How it didn't work (errored, undesired behavior, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6Pb5/3/) showing the things I explain below.

Check [this page](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html) for syntax regarding the Canvas.

If you want to be able to quickly and easily designate random coordinates, you can wrap it up in a function.

```
function randCoord(factor){
    return Math.random() * factor;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
// all of these will go to different points
ctx.moveTo(randCoord(300),randCoord(100));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(300),randCoord(100));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(300),randCoord(100));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(300),randCoord(100));
```

You could set a default scale:

```
function randCoord(factor){
    if (factor == undefined){
        factor = 100;
    }
    return Math.random() * factor;
}
```

Which would allow you to simply write the function name.

```
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(),randCoord());
```

You can also make another function that just adds a random additional point

```
function addRandomPoint(xFactor, yFactor) {
    ctx.lineTo( randCoord(xFactor), randCoord(yFactor) );
}

// these will all add new points
addRandomPoint();
addRandomPoint();
addRandomPoint(200, 300);
addRandomPoint(-100, 25);
```

And then wrap it up in loop to make many points

```
// this will add 10 new points
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    addRandomPoint();
}
```

So you could do this:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth="5";
ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    addRandomPoint();
}
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Thank so much. I'm going to get this integrated and I'll let you know if it's working okay. 
I would green your answer, but I've yet to earn my stripes.
Cheers again.

Comment: You're welcome! @user3178364 are you able to accept the answer? You might not be able to upvote it, but you should be able to select the checkmark.